# Questions related to running an exploratory factor analysis on skewed data

Tags: factor-analysis, psychometrics, exploratory-data-analysis

I want to test overall skewness / normality in a large data set of ordinal data from survey questions.

(I couldn’t use Shapiro wilk as I received an error saying the dataset is too large as it has over 20,000 data points):

boxplot(DATAFRAME)

describe(DATAFRAME)

What functions could I use to transform skewed data into a normal distribution?

What command could be used to test whether the oblimin factor analysis function in r has produced the most simple structure? (My understanding is oblimin does not always produce the most simple structure and that this may need to be adjusted)

And also would you know what functions could be used to determine whether relationships between all pairs of variables are approximately linear, or at any rate not obviously U-shaped or J-shaped?

Would I need to create correlation plots between each variable/question or is there a better set of commands to do this?

(OUTPUT
I received a list of skew and kurtosis values for each question/variable in the data frame using the Describe function however I am looking for some kind of overall value to indicate whether as a whole my data is very skewed and needs to be transformed. I am not sure which commands would be appropriate for the other tasks I am hoping to achieve that I outlined above)

Comment: Welcome to cross-validated! Questions about how to do something in R are off topic, and will be closed. I've tried to make your question more general (as it's about the analysis to use, regardless of whether you are using R or not.)

Comment: It's usually better to ask one question at a time. Don't put multiple questions into one because it makes it hard work to answer them, and then people don't want to. Have a look at: https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: okay no worries thank you!